# How can I troubleshoot why my computer shuts down unexpectedly some time after gaming

Tags: windows-7, power-supply, hardware-failure, shutdown, gaming

I played Shadow of Mordor on optimal settings, the temperatures were good.
After I was done playing, the temperatures got back to normal in seconds of course, yet 5 minutes later my computer just unexpectedly shutted down.

It happened twice today with Shadow of Mordor, and it happened occasionally in the past as-well.
When this happens my computer automatically restarts, but it usually shuts-down unexpectedly again right away. (I try to shut it down before and give it a minute before the restart, just in case it does have to do with temperature, and that got it started up successfully so far even though I don't think temperatures are the issue).

How can I troubleshoot and fix my problem?
I don't know much about hardware, but I have a hunch that this is a PSU issue. Is that likely?
It seems somewhat strange that it only happens after gaming. I can play for hours, but only afterwards it will find a reason to shut-down.

I'm running AMD Radeon R9 290X, with Intel Core i7-4790K, drivers are up to date.

---

The system logged a critical message saying from the kernel-power saying "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly."

Comment: standard issue, standard answer - overheat or underpower. If it's not overheating, then first thing to look at is the PSU. They do get 'tired' over time.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's relatively new, so I suppose underpower (I did add an extra hard-drive, but since day 1 so I can't tell any difference). I'll try to look into it, thank you.

Comment: @MasterMastic 1. It sounds to me like BSOD. Have you looked at the event log? 2. I didn't understand a few things, did the computer completely shutdown or rebooted? 3. Did this ever happened during a game or only afterwards?

Comment: @EliadTech 1. It does? there was no actual BSOD. I have now looked at the log and added the message to my question. 2. It rebooted. 3.  Possibly. Sometimes it misbehaved like that during games and I assumed temperature (although now that I think about it, I don't think it reached really really high ones). Thank you for your response!

Comment: Try replacing components with a known good spare. Also try using a benchmark utility to rule out that specific game as the culprit.

Comment: @MasterMastic The fact the you didn't actually see the BSOD doesn't mean he didn't stopped by for a visit. Try using some benchmark utilities (like http://www.howtogeek.com/111733/how-to-benchmark-your-windows-pc-5-free-benchmarking-tools/), and see if your system crashes and in what point. Also, is the message you've posted the only relevant one you found in the logs?